# Remove datagrid possible WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have the main.xaml where I have a ribbon with some tabs on it.  Basically I have an Articles Tab, Categories Tab, Keywords Tab etc.  What I would like to be able to do is, once I click on the Articles tab, I load the datagrid with the Articles, once I click on the Categories Tab, I load the datagrid with the Categories, and the Keywords the same thing.  I was thinking of creating 3 datagrids, and once a tab is clicked I hide/remove the other 2.  Is this the correct way to do it, and if it is how can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

ok solved

I only needed this

dgCategories.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: recommended aproach is to use TabControl as described by jjrdk (assuming datagrid is within the context and child of Tab).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a ribbon, but in a normal tab control you can set the SelectedContentTemplateSelector property to a DataTemplateSelector. This will provide a given template to the content that you have currently selected. This means that you don't have to worry about adding / removing controls as this will be handled by WPF.

In general when you are faced with changing display of content then I would recommend using a template selector.